# Snakemake Cloud execution command parameters (GCP)

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, snakemake, bucket

I want to use Snakemake on Google Cloud platform, so i used this tutorial : https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html

I did the first steps, then I need to do this : https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v5.8.0/executing/cluster-cloud.html#executing-a-snakemake-workflow-via-kubernetes

After reading the text below, i created a bucket named mybucketname in a project in my GCP account, and my command is :

```
snakemake --kubernetes --use-conda --default-remote-provider GS --default-remote-prefix mybucketname
```

The problem is that I get the error "Error : no Snakefile found, tried Snakefile, snakefile, workflow/Snakefile, workflow/snakefile."

I tried to change the name of the bucket in my command with another bucket name that doesn't exist, and i get the same error; which means the command doesn't find my bucket in GCP.

I haven't speficied a project name in the console (where my bucket is), so maybe it's the solution ? But i don't know how to specify it.

I have also tried to replace mybucketname with the Link URL and Link for gsutil parameters written in my bucket configuration, but it doesn't work

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Take into consideration that a bucket name is considered sensitive information (since they have [an unique identifiable name at the whole Cloud Storage namespace](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets#considerations) independent of the project), so please edit your post and remove this information.

Comment: The specific library you are using gathers the project id when you run ´gcloud init´ during the initial [configuration steps](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v5.8.0/executing/cluster-cloud.html#google-cloud-engine). Notice that as per the docs the commands are meant to be run from within a Compute Engine instance (although I believe you could also run all these commands from the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs).

Comment: Besides making sure that you thoroughly follow the configuration steps mentioned previously, I believe you could also test by changing the ´$PREFIX´ value to ´gs://[CHANGE-ME-FOR-BUCKET-NAME]´ (but I haven't tested if this is the case and I don't know if it's needed).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I tried it but it doesn't work :(